# ASP.Net Core MVC parsing queries for older WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to parse queries for WebForms sites in MVC ASP.Net Core and route it to a controller?

Reason being is that we are in the middle of re-writing an old ASP.Net WebForms app into ASP.Net Core MVC.
Customers access the site by calling the default.aspx page and supplying an id.

Example

```
oursite/Default.aspx?Id=6
```

This obviously won't work as Default.aspx does not exist and is not a controller.

**UPDATE 1:**
Bit more digging and i got this working.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("oldDefault",
                "Default.aspx",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Default"});
        });
```

This works but I don't know how to pass in the query i.e `?Id=6`

**UPDATE 2:**
So I seem to have an issue with ? being in the query.

If I do the following using this url `oursite/Default.aspxId=6`, I get routing with parameter extracted and passed in.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("oldDefault",
                "Default.aspx{id}",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Default"});
```

but I need the ? in the url. So if I then try this

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("oldDefault",
                "Default.aspx?{id}",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Default"});
```

I get the following error.

> RoutePatternException: The literal section 'Default.aspx?' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.

**Current Solution**
Best way, at the moment, to get this to work is by ignore trying to map the parameter and instead get this from the HttpRequest in the action.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("oldDefault",
                "Default.aspx",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Default"});

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Default()
    {
        if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("Id"))
        {
             // Do something...
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something....
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Id as a parameter in the Controllers Action?

Comment: Yes it is. My issue seems to be with the ? in query, see my update 2

Comment: I meant that you could have id as a parameter in the Action method, not in the routing.

Comment: I do? public IActionResult Default(string id)

Comment: Have you tried to put the oldDefault route first?

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work

Comment: ok, sorry . it worked in mvc5 maybe diffrent in core...